# single quote in php from java string

Tags: java, php

I have a java (android) application that uses php to talk to the MS database. The problem is one part in my app. I have a string that is a sql statement, and that string will not insert into the database with the single quotes

```
String sql = "select * from table where col = 'testing' AND Col2 = 'Tester'";
```

I get that in the php script by using: `$script = $_REQUEST['Script'];`

2 things, I want to insert that script into a a column with the datatype char 
and i also want to run that script as well. Thanks!

I am not having the users run there own scripts on my DB. as they check a checkbox it a StringBuilder builds a script upon what they select. So if they check Female or male The String add the Select * from Table where Gender = 'Female' etc.

Comment: You seriously allow user-supplied SQL to be executed against your database?  What happens when they issue `DROP TABLE table`?

Comment: @cdhowie since they know the name of the table, we might assume this is in a trusted environment.

Comment: @Mark, I'm not convinced any such environment really exists.

Comment: @El Yobo sure, there's the 'you drop the table, you get fired, then we restore a backup' environment. Or the '4 people work here' environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember, strings in MSSQL are represented with double quotes.

```
$var = "select ... where col = \"testing\"";
$var = 'select ... where col = "testing"'; // more readable
```

Just use it this way.

If you only receive those queries, consider replacing ' with " using str_replace. I am aware of the fact it may not be correct for all cases but simple ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$script = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Script']);
```

Comment: This is a ms sql not mysql doest that make a difference? and also Will this insert it into a table with the quotes?

Comment: Not sure actually but since it's a PHP function it *should* work. I don't have MSSQL running so you'll have to test it.